# Percentage of number of documents falling under time filter to the total number of document in a Kibana Index Pattern

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7

I have a time based index pattern in Kibana. I want to show following metric on Kibana dashboard.

> A percentage of the number of document falling under the global time
>   filter to the total number of document present in the index pattern.

► *For Example,*

> The percentage of the number of document in the last 2 days to the total number of document present in the index pattern. Here the user has applied the time filter to the last 2 days.

Can it, at all, be visualized using Kibana? How?

Comment: In ES you have an Index. In Kibana, let's say you created an Index-Pattern (ID: human readable name instead of the default alpha-numberic) which points to the ES index.
Inject data to ES Index (lets say you sent csv/json data, where data/doc row fields are mapped using a config file, int/text/keyword/float/date field types etc). You can possibly use Rest API (write a script) to query a given Index data and then create a 3 column csv file. Doc_ID, Date_Doc_ID_Got_Added, Total_Docs_in_ES. Your index-pattern's `timeFieldValue` = `Date_Doc_ID_Got_Added` & you can use Kibana MATH to visualize it.

Comment: Get the CSV created from a given ES index. Now send this csv data to an new ES index (call it: percentage_docs_vs_all_docs) i.e. keep it separate and create a new Kibana-Index Pattern `"percentage_docs_vs_all_docs"` (i.e ID) and it's title (i.e. it's pattern/regex) = `"percentage_docs_vs_all_docs*"` and `timeFieldValue` will be that Date field (2nd column) and all you have to now do, is, re-create this csv file, recreate the new ES Index and Kibana Index-Pattern periodically and your visualization will show latest data & will time-span (as `time Value Field` or `timeFieldValue` is that date.

Comment: Title/pattern is what you see in Kibana GUI when you click on Index-Patterns (under / after clicking Gear button). If you hover over using your mouse on that index-pattern, you'll see the ID (in the statusbar .. URL the value after last `/` character). If you have created Kibana Index-Pattern using GUI, it'll show a long alpha-numberic number (it's recommended to avoid using Kibana GUI to created Index-Patterns as alpha-numeric IDs are hard to remember or causes a bit work in automation when it comes to recreating indexes/index-patterns).